# Optimization: How should i Optimize the Linq Concat of Collections? C#

Tags: c#, linq, collections, design-patterns

is there any way i can Optimize this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GenerateCombinedPatterns
    (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> patterns1,
     IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> patterns2)
{
    return patterns1
           .Join(patterns2, p1key => 1, p2key => 1, (p1, p2) => p1.Concat(p2))
           .Where(r => r.Sum() <= stockLen)
           .AsParallel()
        as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>;
}
```

Comment: You can skip the "as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>" part. It's implicit.

Comment: Is the data coming from database?

Comment: No its not its an operation on a collection of stuff thats being imported from a file. i've checked the other areas.. the File Import and export do not take time .. and even the generation of patterns .. but this block of code seems to slow everything down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for every combination, use `SelectMany` instead, usually performed with multiple "from" clauses:

```
return from p1 in patterns1
       from p2 in patterns2
       let combination = p1.Concat(p2)
       where combination.Sum() <= stockLen
       select combination;
```

That's without any parallelism though... depending on the expected collections, I'd probably *just* parallelize at one level, e.g.

```
return from p1 in patterns1.AsParallel()
       from p2 in patterns2
       let combination = p1.Concat(p2)
       where combination.Sum() <= stockLen
       select combination;
```

Note that there's no guarantee as to the order in which the results come out with the above - you'd need to tweak it if you wanted the original ordering.

Answer (score 1):

No point in making the query parallel at the very end.  **Update:** Jon was right, my initial solution was incorrect and turns out my corrected solution was essentially the same as his.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GenerateCombinedPatterns
    (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> patterns1,
     IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> patterns2)
{
    var parallel1 = patterns1.AsParallel();
    return parallel1.SelectMany(p1 => patterns2.Select(p2 => p1.Concat(p2)))
        .Where(r => r.Sum() <= stockLen);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this does the same thing as the original.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at that Join() and at second look, perhaps was a flattening instead which was my initial guess.

Comment: if I add.AsParallel then the application seems to take around 6 times the time it takes if its not used.

Comment: Thanks Jeff and Jon.
My Original Code runs on a set of Inputs for 14 seconds. Trying out Jeff's code,hangs the application.